# OnKeyListener, onKeyDown() No event propagation when a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-button

**EDIT:**
***Problem solved***

1)
thanks for @geekCode, I was using 4.4W where w is short for wearable, after I change android emulator to Android 4.1.2, the **ConnectionException** problem is solved.

2) 
I was misleading by the example code, it says "Click Me", so previously I click the button using mouse, and nothing happened. Then I do the research about **KeyEvent**, the Android API explains **event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN** as ***getAction() value: the key has been pressed down.***  I pressed a random key on keyboard, the log shows up!
[image]

Thanks again everyone.

```
08-11 14:53:36.911    3020-3020/org.crazyit.event V/-MyButton-﹕ the onKeyDown in MyButton
08-11 14:53:36.911    3020-3020/org.crazyit.event V/-Activity-﹕ the onKeyDown in Activity
08-11 14:53:37.101    3020-3020/org.crazyit.event V/-Listener-﹕ the onKeyDown in Listener
08-11 14:53:37.101    3020-3020/org.crazyit.event V/-MyButton-﹕ the onKeyDown in MyButton
08-11 14:53:37.101    3020-3020/org.crazyit.event V/-Activity-﹕ the onKeyDown in Activity
```

**Previous Question:**

I'm new to Android, and learning how to propagate (all callback methods return false) events when a button is clicked. Here's the screenshot and source code:

[image]

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet set){
        super(context, set);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        Log.v("-MyButton-", " the onKeyDown in MyButton");
        return false;
    }
}

public class Propagation extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bn = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.bn);

        bn.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Log.v("-Listener-", "the onKeyDown in Listenr");
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        Log.v("-Activity-", "the onKeyDown in Activity");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is expected to display the verbose **Log** messages, unfortunately nothing showed up.

Another odd thing is that Im using IntelliJ IDEA shows that:

```
08-11 19:31:08.241    1367-1488/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn? Socket closed
08-11 19:31:08.241    1367-1488/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn? Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
08-11 19:31:11.941    1335-1508/com.google.android.wearable.app W/NotifManCompat? Giving up on delivering 1 tasks to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.stream.NotificationSideChannelService} after 7 retries
08-11 19:31:12.261    1367-1488/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn? Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
08-11 19:31:12.271    1367-1488/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn? Error writing to device
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
```

All I can figure out is the program is working, but there's no propagation when the button "Click Me" is clicked, and why is ConnectionException is thrown?

Comment: are you developing for wearable devicess??

Comment: in logcat, you're looking for the code that tells you the error that gets thrown by the OS, and the line that is causing the problem - usually begins with `at com.foo.... java:###`

Comment: I created an android emulator(Android 4.4W) using IntelliJ IDEA, no other specs. You remind me, maybe the  W after 4.4 is short for Wearable

Comment: @SQLiteNoob I tried, but it seems that there's no exception is thrown from my code.